# Vuetify text field border missing

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm trying to implement Veutify's [text field](https://vuetifyjs.com/components/text-fields)

This is what it looks like for me right now:
[image]

And this is what it looks like when the text field is in focus:
[image]

These are my imports in main.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuetify from 'vuetify';
Vue.use(Vuetify);
```

Am I missing an import or something?

Comment: Where's the CSS import? You should ideally use your browser's developer tools to inspect the styles for the element

Comment: @Phil I removed it because adding `import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';` didn't do anything. And there doesn't seem to be anything relating `border` border in my browser's CSS styles.

Comment: I think it uses box-shadow for the underline. Compare your element to the one in their example / demo pages

Comment: @Phil Only difference I found is the **transitions**. [example](http://imgur.com/e41tUgG) vs [mine](http://imgur.com/GUlZODm)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I ran in the same issue, you need to wrap your application in a `<v-app>`.

The reason is that the border's color depends on the theme you're using. If you try to inspect the documentation you will see that the border's rule is something like `.application--light .input-group .input-group__details`: `application--light` is indeed a class added by `v-app`.

Comment: not working. I wrapped the App.vue (the main component) inside the <v-app><v-content></v-content></v-app>. Still not working.

Comment: @Soorya My issue was that I used custom js colors in theme configuration and has written `export default { primary: 'rgb(...)'}`. `rgb()` calls are not supported in js, and it just applied white as primary color. If this is the case for you, switch to hex colors

Answer (score 0):

Same issue
But I fixed by this solution.
Please add this link(CDN) to you html file.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-material/dist/vue-material.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-material/dist/theme/default.css">


<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-material"></script>
```

Don't worry
no crashing.