# Text field from Vuetify has no underline

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to use vuetify's text field. It looks like this:
[image: before_focus]

After applying focus it looks like this:

[image: after_focus]

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45579658/vuetify-text-field-border-missing) this, but my app IS wrapped in v-app. Is there anything else I could try?

HINT:
Dark theme doesn't work for me as well,but for example, I can use classes like "red", "text--red", to apply colors.

Proof, that there is v-app involved below:
[image]

EDIT:
I tried to wrap it with v-content as well, but it didn't help.

```
<v-app>
  <v-content>
    <router-view></router-view>
  </v-content>
</v-app>
```

[image]

Comment: what's your `vuetify` version?

Comment: My version is 0.16.9

Comment: And I don't see `v-content` in your screenshot. Can you wrap your content in `v-content` also and see if that helps? check docs for `v-content` example: https://vuetifyjs.com/vuetify/quick-start

Comment: I have added it, but it doesn't work - see updated question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

unpkg.com links to the latest version of vuetify, which is currently 0.17.0. To use 0.16.9 css from unpkg you have to use this link: `https://unpkg.com/vuetify@0.16.9/dist/vuetify.min.css`

Comment: thanks! Your fix and my fix are almost same fix, but yours seems more generic :)

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by removing

```
<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

from index.html, and adding

```
import '../node_modules/vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css';
```

to main.js file.

Dunno why it worked though.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the fix was to add margin-bottom 1px to the input element. Hope it helps.