# V-text-field in VuetifyJS

Tags: css, vuejs2, vuetify.js

How to override a v-text-field?

Actually I am trying to make a text field that should initially have a thin line over which a label/placeholder will be displayed. When I click on it, the label must float up (like a superscript) and that line should become slightly thick along with change in color.

In Vuetifyjs such a text-field exists , but when I copy paste the component , nothing of that sort is happening. The colour isn't changing , infact when that text field is not selected , we cannot see any sort of line , just the label.

I tried using class="input-group--focused" but in that case , the label is already Floated up. The line is present but its opacity is high , ie its black instead of grey. Please help me , it would be great.

I looked at my dependencies , I am running the latest version of vuetifyjs: 1.0.10

Something like a GMail login Form

Comment: Wait, you mean `v-text-field` does not behave like it should? Probably you need to reproduce it, or at least show some code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I'll give it a go and presume you didn't wrap your app in `v-app`

From [docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/getting-started/quick-start):

> **In order for** your **application to work properly**, **you must wrap it in a**
>   `v-app` component. This component is used for dynamically managing your
>   content area and is the mounting point for many components.

```
<div id="app">
    <v-app>
        Put <v-text-field /> somewhere inside
    </v-app>
</div>
```

And of course, check [example layouts](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/layout/pre-defined) and see which one works for you.

If it doesn't work, see [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47316297/text-field-from-vuetify-has-no-underline) where OP included `v-app`.